# How to write the response from tFileFetch to a tLogRow in Talend?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I'm using tFileFetch POST to upload a multipart form file to the server. I can print the response to the console. Is it possible to get this response written to a tLogRow or a text file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tFixedFlowInput to generate some arbitrary data, so this should work for you. You can use it to emit the value that you are reading from globalMap.

tFixedFlowInput->tLogRow

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you could print the response to console, in that case you could `tJava` to set the `PrintStream` to file.

At the beginning of your job have a `tJava` (you could set up `tPreJob` and connect `tJava`) with the code snippet as -

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C:/Talend/"+jobName+"Log.txt");
java.io.PrintStream ps = new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream(file));
System.setOut(ps);
```

This would ensure that all the output/response would be written/redirected to file.